# PHP SimpleXMLElement object get data

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<Root>
    <personalData>
        <userName>John Tom</userName>
        <email>mail@example.com</email>
    </personalData>
    <profesionalData>
        <job>engineer</job>
        <jobId>16957</jobId>
    </profesionalData>
</Root>
```

Doing in my debugger:

```
$myObject->xpath('//Root/profesionalData')
```

I have:

```
: array = 
  0: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
    job: string = engineer    
    jobId: string = 16957
```

I cannot get hold of the `jobId` `16957`.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Try `$myObject->xpath('//Root/profesionalData')[0]->jobId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$root = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');


$job_ids = $root->xpath('//profesionalData/jobId');

if (!$job_ids) {
  die("Job IDs not found");
}

foreach ($job_ids as $id) {
  // SimpleXmlElement implements __toString method, so
  // you can fetch the vlaue by casting the object to string.
  $id = (string)$id;
  var_dump($id);
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
string(5) "16957"
```

**Notes**

You don't need to specify `Root` in the XPath expression, if you are going to fetch all `profesionalData/jobId` tags no matter where they are in the document, just use the double slash (`//`) expression. This approach may be convenient in cases, when you want to avoid registering the XML namespaces. Otherwise, you can use a strict expression like `/Root/profesionalData/jobId` (path from the root). By the way, your current expression (`//Root/profesionalData/jobId`) matches all occurrences of `/Root/profesionalData/jobId` in the document, e.g. `/x/y/z/Root/profesionalData/jobId`.

Since `SimpleXmlElement::xpath` function returns an array on success, or `FALSE` on failure, you should iterate the value with a loop, if it is a non-empty array.

`SimpleXmlElement` implements [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method. The method is called when the object appears in a string context. In particular, you can [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the object to string in order to fetch string content of the node.

Comment: Er.. This will always fail because of your `if`!

Comment: The first note is wrong. `//` does not point to the 'Root' element but it is a reference to its parent node (in this case). A `/` at the start of an location path points to the document itself, `//` is the descendant axis. So `//Root/profesionalData` will look for any `profesionalData` element node that is a direct child of an `Root` element node.